# Cannot modified checkbox with javascript

Tags: javascript, checkbox

I have this code in html I want to change the checkbox check and uncheck event using javascript on some event so I am calling `function ChangeCheckBox()` on button click

```
<div>
    <label class="checkbox line">
        <input type="checkbox" id="Add" />Add</label>
</div>
<script>
    function ChangeCheckBox() {
        var AddCheck = 0;
        if (AddCheck == 1) {
            document.getElementById("Add").checked = true;
        } else {
            document.getElementById("Add").checked = false;
        }
    }
</script>
```

So in above condition check box should unchecked but its not happening checkbox is remaining checked after running this code

Comment: the if block is redundant. 

The if wont execute ever as you are setting AddCheck = 0 always in this function.It will always land in the else block

Comment: means can you be more specific please

Comment: Its just a piece if code i posted is to understand actual code AddCheck is dynamic and it sets according to some conditions

Answer (score 3):

Since you are setting `AddCheck = 0;`, of course it will not keep it's state, because you are reseting the value. If you want to simulate a toggle, here's a simpler alternative.

```
<script>
    function ChangeCheckBox() {
        var el = document.getElementById("Add");
        el.checked = !el.checked;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Ok there is not problem with my if box the values are ruuning perfectly this is a sample code to understand my problem. Actual code differs. My problem is just i cannot programitically check uncheck the check boxes.

Comment: @Snehal I am not sure what the actual problem is then. It sounds like a logic error. Here's a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/vsxa8gf3/ to help you out.

Comment: Dude its 100% not a logical error it is a syntax error

Comment: This is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/kirtesh08/okbc5vb9/ I dont know its not working properly but I explain the functionality when  click on Second Level it pageId will go in textbox below permissions from there we can select the permissions and when on clcik of second page the permission will go as per selection

Comment: Even i tried u r code with mine code but its not toggleing the check box u can see the same code in fiddle

Comment: I took a long look at your code, and really, the problem was with `AddPermission`. Because the change events were firing, only the first checkbox could possibly set the value. Here's an updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/okbc5vb9/2/  Additionally, please follow the standards on naming in javascript, variables are camel, not pascal case.

Comment: The fiddle u provide uncheck all the checkbox even if there is a data lik if it sets some checkbox to 1 then it should be check when clicked again. It remains checks only both contains some kind of pattern 11000 and 11000 but it wont work if any of the pattern is different 10010 10001

Comment: I believe the problem is with your `$('#checkbox').attr('checked', true)`, when it should be `$('#checkbox').prop('checked', true)`.  Here's the update http://jsfiddle.net/okbc5vb9/4/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88692/discussion-between-candide-and-snehal).

Answer (score 0):

How do you link 'ChangeCheckBox()' to your button ? Can you post this code too ?

The problem is probably because the button refresh your page and so, the checkbox return to it initial state.

Comment: `<a href=# onclick=ChangeCheckBox()>Change</a>` I guess there is no refreshing problem